# Validation function using both for-loops and indexes at the same time

Tags: python, validation

This function iterates through a open dialog box that has 4 values in it all optional except for `aircraft1, aircraft2, warning_or_alert`.

1. `aircraft1`, `aircraft2`
2. `t_sep` # time value in format 00:12:21
3. `t_min_nm` # time value in format 00:21:21
4. `c_tracks` # can be either 'on' or 'off'
5. `warning_or_alert` # can be either 'warning' or 'alert'

First I check if I have correct airplanes `aircraft_str = aircraft1 + ' - ' + aircraft2`. If I have correct aircraft I check if I have `warning_or_alert`. If that is correct I can validate the last three variables `t_sep, t_min_nm, c_tracks`. Don't worry about `errorhandling.stca_list_exception`; it's a function in a different module that handles me error as well is `utils.time_in_range` that function compares two times.

My concern here is my looping technic, by having `for` loops but I'm using indexes instead of the for loop functionality `utils.time_in_range(t_sep, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+2].text)` for instance.

```
def stca_list(aircraft1=None, aircraft2=None, t_sep=None, t_min_nm=None, c_tracks=None, warning_or_alert):
    aircraft_str = None
    if aircraft1:
        aircraft_str = aircraft1 + ' - ' + aircraft2
    stca_list_dialog = squishtest.waitForObject("{type='isds::StcaListDialog' unnamed='1' visible='1' windowTitle='STCA List'}")
    for si in squishtest.object.children(stca_list_dialog):
        if squishtest.className(si) == 'QTableWidget':
            for i, ssi in enumerate(squishtest.object.children(si)):
                if squishtest.className(ssi) == 'QModelIndex':
                    for stca_list_value in squishtest.object.children(si)[i+1:]:
                        if aircraft_str == stca_list_value.text:
                            if warning_or_alert == 'warning':
                                if stca_list_value.foregroundColor == '#FFFFFF00': # yellow
                                    if t_sep:
                                        utils.time_in_range(t_sep, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+2].text)

                                    if t_min_nm:
                                        utils.time_in_range(t_min_nm, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+3].text)

                                    if c_tracks and c_tracks != squishtest.object.children(si)[i+4].text:
                                        raise AssertionError("Error CTracks: Expected[%s] got[%s]"c_tracks, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+4].text)

                                    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject("{name='CloseButton' text='Close' type='QPushButton' visible='1'}"))
                                    return
                                else:
                                    errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error Warning: expected[warning] got[alert]')
                            elif warning_or_alert == 'alert':
                                if stca_list_value.foregroundColor == '#FFFF0000': # red
                                    if t_sep:
                                        utils.time_in_range(t_sep, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+2].text)

                                    if t_min_nm:
                                        utils.time_in_range(t_min_nm, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+3].text)

                                    if c_tracks and c_tracks != squishtest.object.children(si)[i+4].text:
                                        raise AssertionError("Error CTracks: Expected[%s] got[%s]"c_tracks, squishtest.object.children(si)[i+4].text)

                                    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject("{name='CloseButton' text='Close' type='QPushButton' visible='1'}"))
                                    return
                                else:
                                    errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error alert: expect[alert] got[waning]')
                            else:
                                errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Warning or Alert Error: Choose either warning or ellert, [%s] does not exis.' % warning_or_alert)
                        else:
                            errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Are value but wrong expected[%s] but was[%s]' % (aircraft_str, stca_list_value.text))

    if aircraft_str:
        errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error: No warnings or alerts, but got aircraft[%s] and aircraft[%s] and warning or alert[%s]' % (aircraft1, aircraft2, warning_or_alert))

    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject("{name='CloseButton' text='Close' type='QPushButton' visible='1'}"))
```

Comment: Please update the title and the description with information on *what* this function is (supposed to be) doing, because it is obvious that it has lots of nested loops; also please check that the indentation is now correct.

Comment: Btw. could you please describe `errorhandling.stca_list_exception`: Is that raising an actual exception or not?

Comment: The desire to improve code is implied for all questions on this site. Question titles should reflect the purpose of the code, not how you wish to have it reworked. See [ask].

Comment: I took all your advices and refactored the whole question.

Comment: @JonB thanks for the clarifications; though I still worry about the `stca_list_exception` because *if* it raises and exits from this function, that is entirely different than not doing it. I'd also rename it if it doesn't.

Comment: @ferada `errorhandling.stca_list_exception` it indeed raises an error and exits the function, it's input is just the error string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that this is so complex is that instead of doing the sequence
"find widget in question" - "process it", the code is doing something
like "iterate over all widgets" - "if one is the widget in question,
process it and exit", so it ends up with a lot of nesting instead of a
flat sequence of steps.

So, I'd rewrite it to first, find the object, one with class
`QTableWidget`, which has a child with class `QModelIndex`, which has
exactly one entry with some specific text.  Then, use that entry and do
some assertions.

---

Some more general remarks:

- The variable names aren't the best, i.e. not descriptive of the kinds
  of values they contain.
- The messages have some typos; I've changed them where I could.
- Maybe import more; the constant repetitions of `errorhandling` and
  `squishtest` are quite verbose.
- `aircraft_str` could be initialised on one line like
  `aircraft_str = aircraft1 and '{} - {}'.format(aircraft1, aircraft2)`
  or even with
  `aircraft_str = '{} - {}'.format(aircraft1, aircraft2) if aircraft1 else None`.
  If you're consistently using `%` for string formatting of course use
  that instead.
- The test for `aircraft_str` at the end should be `if aircraft1:`
  instead, because that is directly related to one of the input
  variables and `aircraft_str` is more formatting than logic IMO.
- Exit loops early, don't nest so much.  E.g. if you have a single `if`,
  invert the test and `continue` in a loop.
- The use of the index `i` in that way is error prone and, depending on
  what `squishtest.object.children(si)` does, costly.  IMO, since you
  access by index anyway, don't use `enumerate` then, but destructure
  the first five items at the start of the corresponding loop and reuse
  the variables (and give them nice names so we know what the widgets
  are).
- Input verification should be done early.  So if `warning_or_alert` can
  have one of two values, the check for that should come once, before
  the rest of the function (the value could also be cached for faster
  execution and less code duplication).  That way not only is the test
  not execute too often (that is, more than once), but it is very clear
  that the variable can only have a valid value for the rest of the
  function, so reasoning about the state is much easier.  It's also much
  more self-documenting when reading the source.  An actual `raise
  stca_list_exception` would also make clear that this raises an
  exception.
- The colours are documented, but I'd still move them into separate
  variables to aid readability.
- Both branches of the `if` switch on `warning_or_alert` are almost
  identical.  That should factored out.  The `AssertionError` is also
  weirdly called, it looks like the string formatting is actually
  missing there.  E.g. why not have a `expected_color` variable so that
  it can be checked without branching?

With all that in mind, it could look like this, note the nested loop is
still there, but it already looks much cleaner:

```python
def stca_list(aircraft1=None, aircraft2=None, t_sep=None, t_min_nm=None, c_tracks=None, warning_or_alert):
    aircraft_str = aircraft1 and '{} - {}'.format(aircraft1, aircraft2)

    if warning_or_alert not in ('warning', 'alert'):
        errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Warning or Alert Error: Choose either warning or alert, [%s] does not exist.' % warning_or_alert)

    is_warning = warning_or_alert == 'warning'
    expected_color = YELLOW if is_warning else RED

    stca_list_dialog = squishtest.waitForObject("{type='isds::StcaListDialog' unnamed='1' visible='1' windowTitle='STCA List'}")

    for si in squishtest.object.children(stca_list_dialog):
        if squishtest.className(si) != 'QTableWidget':
            continue

        children = squishtest.object.children(si)

        for i, ssi in enumerate(children):
            if squishtest.className(ssi) != 'QModelIndex':
                continue

            for stca_list_value in children[i+1:]:
                if aircraft_str != stca_list_value.text:
                    errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Are value but wrong expected[%s] but was[%s]' % (aircraft_str, stca_list_value.text))

                if stca_list_value.foregroundColor != expected_color:
                    errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error Warning: expected[%s] got[%s]' % ('alert' if is_warning else 'warning', warning_or_alert)

                if t_sep:
                    utils.time_in_range(t_sep, children[i+2].text)

                if t_min_nm:
                    utils.time_in_range(t_min_nm, children[i+3].text)

                if c_tracks and c_tracks != children[i+4].text:
                    raise AssertionError("Error CTracks: Expected[%s] got[%s]" % (c_tracks, children[i+4].text))

                squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject("{name='CloseButton' text='Close' type='QPushButton' visible='1'}"))
                return

    if aircraft1:
        errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error: No warnings or alerts, but got aircraft[%s] and aircraft[%s] and warning or alert[%s]' % (aircraft1, aircraft2, warning_or_alert))

    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject("{name='CloseButton' text='Close' type='QPushButton' visible='1'}"))
```

However having the assertions *in* the loop still looks bad and there's
the `return` and the duplicated "waiting for click on close button".  So
now I'd move the finding of the objects in question out of there to
simplify the logic.  The function will return the four widgets if it
matches the condition, otherwise it will (by default) return `None`:

```python
def find_stca_list_value():
    stca_list_dialog = squishtest.waitForObject("{type='isds::StcaListDialog' unnamed='1' visible='1' windowTitle='STCA List'}")

    for si in squishtest.object.children(stca_list_dialog):
        if squishtest.className(si) != 'QTableWidget':
            continue

        children = squishtest.object.children(si)

        for i, ssi in enumerate(children):
            if squishtest.className(ssi) != 'QModelIndex':
                continue

            return children[i+1:i+4]
```

Waiting for the close button can also be a separate function, or it
could be nested in `stca_list` as well:

```python
def wait_for_close_button():
    squishtest.clickButton(squishtest.waitForObject("{name='CloseButton' text='Close' type='QPushButton' visible='1'}"))
```

Now the actual function is reasonably short and the logic is easier to
see.  `children1` to `children3` still need better names!

```python
def stca_list(aircraft1=None, aircraft2=None, t_sep=None, t_min_nm=None, c_tracks=None, warning_or_alert):
    if warning_or_alert not in ('warning', 'alert'):
        errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Warning or Alert Error: Choose either warning or alert, [%s] does not exist.' % warning_or_alert)

    result = find_stca_list_value()

    if not result:
        if aircraft1:
            errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error: No warnings or alerts, but got aircraft[%s] and aircraft[%s] and warning or alert[%s]' % (aircraft1, aircraft2, warning_or_alert))

        wait_for_close_button()
        return

    stca_list_value, children2, children3, children4 = result

    aircraft_str = aircraft1 and '%s - %s' % (aircraft1, aircraft2)
    if aircraft_str != stca_list_value.text:
        errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Are value but wrong expected[%s] but was[%s]' % (aircraft_str, stca_list_value.text))

    is_warning = warning_or_alert == 'warning'
    if stca_list_value.foregroundColor != (YELLOW if is_warning else RED):
        errorhandling.stca_list_exception('Error Warning: expected[%s] got[%s]' % ('alert' if is_warning else 'warning', warning_or_alert))

    if t_sep:
        utils.time_in_range(t_sep, children2.text)

    if t_min_nm:
        utils.time_in_range(t_min_nm, children3.text)

    if c_tracks and c_tracks != children4.text:
        raise AssertionError("Error CTracks: Expected[%s] got[%s]" % (c_tracks, children4.text))

    wait_for_close_button()
```